# Macos uninstall pip and start over

Tags: python, macos, pip

I'm new to macos and trying to get a dev environment going...I need pip but  getting an error message with just `pip`.

Getting error `pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: The 'pip==20.0.2' distribution was not found and is required by the application`

Python3 was installed with macos and I tried to install 2.x version and made it the  global default. I think that's why I'm getting the above error.

I uninstalled the 2.x python using pyenv.

How can I remove pip (i've got pip, pip3 and pip 3.8) and start over.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try removing pip using this in the directory where pip pacakge is installed?
`sudo rm -r pip <Version Number>`

You can get the directory where pip is installed with this: `which pip` and then `cd` into that path and run the above command.